# Setting FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE in Visual Studio

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I would like to know whether it is possible to call a CreateFile Function in Visual C++ to create a file with attribute FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE (0x00000040 hex, 64 decimal). According to the MSDN API, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE is reserved and therefore I cannot use it, but I know there must be some way to create a file with such attributes. What must I do to do this? Are there other API calls, or do I need to make a new struct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag exists to identify handles that represent devices rather than files. For example, using CreateFile to open `\\.\C:` returns a handle to the drive *device*, rather than a file or directory handle.

You cannot create a new 'file' with this flag, since a file is not a device. Inventing/creating (rather than opening) a file handle with this flag requires writing a device driver to provide one (specifically, you create a name for your device object that a user-mode client can pass to CreateFile - the kernel creates the file handle and sets the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE flag).

The [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) page and the Remarks section of the [DeviceIOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216.aspx) page should clarify things a bit further.

Comment: Interestingly, while CreateFile on `\\.\C:` succeeds, [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx) fails (returning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER on Win XP and ERROR_BAD_DEV_TYPE under Wine 1.9.23) instead of returning FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE.